# how many symmetric relations are there on a set with 5 elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know that on a set with $n$ elements there are $2^{\frac12(n^2+n)}$ symmetric relations, but is it different on sets with specific number of elements?

Comment: You have a result valid for any $n\in\Bbb N$ and are asking whether is it invalid for any _specific_ value of $n$? What would you imagine? Maybe it fails for $n=\pi$?

Answer (score 2):

The statement that a set with $n$ elements has $2^{(n^2+n)/2}$ symmetric relations is intented to convey that the statement is true if $n$ is replaced by any specific number. In particular:

$$
\begin{array}{rclrrl}
\text{A set with} & 0 & \text{elements has} & 2^{(0^2+0)/2} = & 1 & \text{symmetric relation}\\
\text{A set with} & 1 & \text{element  has} & 2^{(1^2+1)/2} = & 2 & \text{symmetric relations}\\
\text{A set with} & 2 & \text{elements has} & 2^{(2^2+2)/2} = & 8 & \text{symmetric relations}\\
\text{A set with} & 3 & \text{elements has} & 2^{(3^2+3)/2} = & 64 & \text{symmetric relations}\\
\end{array}
$$

and so on.

Sometimes the statement will begin “**For each $n$**, a set with $n$ elements has…” to emphasize this.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly any mathematical expression(made up of at least one variable) is valid in the  domain's of the respective variables. Here in the mathematical expression for no. of symmetric relations the variable we have is $n$ whose domain is predefined to be $\mathbb N$ (Natural Numbers). So using any other $n$ is illegal.